# Realize where the user is clicking inside the input

Tags: reactjs, input, focus, emoji

I am using reactjs.

The client has an input field, he can type in it and whenether he clicks on an emoji from the emoji picker of our chat, it adds up the emoji to the input. Like this:

```
let currentMessage = this.state.message;
await this.setState({ message: currentMessage + emoji.native });
```

The thing is, I have never thought about it in depth but you actually need to first recognize where the user's cursor is. For example, if you go to twitter and type hello, then click right between "h" and "e" and press on the emoji icon, the emoji will be added between them. In my case, the emoji will always be added to the end of the input.

What I need is to understand how I can know on which letter or placement the focus is on. From there I will probably manage.

How can I do that?

Comment: Check out this: `field.selectionStart`. It's pure JS

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do such thing is to watch for cursor position within an input with [selectionStart](https://caniuse.com/#search=selectionStart) method

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this thread in the future. This is how my code ended up

```
const inputElement = await document.getElementById("message");
        let currentIndex = inputElement.selectionStart;

        let currentMessage = this.state.message;
        let messagePartOne = currentMessage.slice(0, currentIndex);
        let messagePartTwo = currentMessage.slice(
          currentIndex,
          currentMessage.length
        );

        await this.setState({
          message: messagePartOne + emoji.native + messagePartTwo,
        });
        let newMessageLength = await this.state.message.length;

        this.setState({
          messageLength: newMessageLength,
          remainingLetters: this.state.remainingLetters - emoji.native.length,
        });
        inputElement.focus();
        inputElement.setSelectionRange(currentIndex + 2, currentIndex + 2);
```

First, you need to get the element id of your input.

After that, you get the current message that you have in the input. You recognize where the cursor is and split the text into two parts. Before the emoji, and after the emoji.

Now, you connect them all together in the right order: FirstString + Emoji + SecondString.

The last stage is to focus the cursor on the right place in case that the user wants to press again on the emoji icon and paste more than one.